# React-router-dom and Redirect not being added to history?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

**Outline:**

I'm currently trying to learn `react/redux/router`. As a practice project, I'm working on a basic contact/client management app. While using `react-router-dom`s `Redirect` component. I can't get the back/forward navigation to work as expected.

**Details:**

I have a table with a list of entries located at `/contacts/` and when you click on one of the table rows, I want to `Redirect` using a value set by the `<tr>`s onClick attribute.

The click on `<tr key={d._id} onClick={()=>this.setState({ id: d._id })}>` changes `state.id` to the `clientID`s unique value. This results in a `Redirect` being true in the tables render method, triggering the `Redirect`.

```
render() { // render method of '/contacts/' {Contacts} component
    return(
        ... // table head
        { this.state.id && <Redirect to={"/contacts/card/"+this.state.id}/> }
        ...// table content
    )
}
```

This is the router which is located in the parent `App.js`

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename="/" >
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <main>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                        <Route 
                            exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/contacts/card/:clientID" component={ContactCard}/>
                    </Switch>
                </main>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

**Question:**

After the redirect, if you click the back button from `/contacts/card/:clientID`, the browser doesn't go back to `/contacts/`. instead, it cycles through any previous `:clientID` URLs that I've looked at.

I have tried wrapping the `<tr>` in a router `<Link to={}>` tag, but it destroyed styles.

**Caveat:** (`this.state.id`)

I know that I should be using `Redux` to hold the value of `this.state.id` for my redirect function. I haven't fully grasped how to mange multiple values with a single redux reducer yet. I will update question with the appropriate method once I do.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed to add `push` to my `<Redirect/>` component like so.

```
<Redirect push to={`/contacts/card/${this.state.id}`}/>
```

From the docs:

> `<Redirect/>`
>
> **push: bool**
>
> When true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

Comment: Thanks for this - was scratching my head for hours.