# Browser back button isn't getting history after Redirect with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Routes look like:

```
    <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
    <Route path="/Buyer" exact component={Buyer} />
    <Route path="/Seller" exact component={Seller} />
```

And inside of Landing I have a conditional Redirect that redirects to either buyer or seller which flows like:

```
<Button fluid onClick={this.routeChange}>Seller</Button>

routeChange(e) {
   this.setState({navigateTo: `/${e.target.textContent}`})
}

if (this.state.navigateTo.length > 0) {
   return <Redirect to={this.state.navigateTo} />
}
```

This works. But, after I redirect, if I hit the back button it seems I have no history of having been at my "/" route. So my back button takes me to wherever I was before that.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a parent component `BrowserRouter` for your app?

Comment: I do. My app is wrapped in <BrowserRouter> in my index.

Comment: I missed the 'push' value for Redirect in the documentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731207/react-router-dom-and-redirect-not-being-added-to-history

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router-dom and Redirect not being added to history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731207/react-router-dom-and-redirect-not-being-added-to-history)