# React Router DOM - Redirect component does not render route properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I realized this has been asked before, please bear with me since I am still learning this. And I think I've tried all solutions in SO but without luck.

**The issue is**: When `PrivateRoute` redirects to `/sign_in`, it's not rendering the expected component (`SignInForm`)

I have implemented a `PrivateRoute` as following;

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// Simplified and still can reproduce the issue;
class PrivateRoute extends Route {
  render () {
    return (<Redirect to="/sign_in" />);
  }
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: !!state.user.token
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute));
```

And this is where I use it;

**index.js**

```
<div className="content position-relative">
    <div className="content-container font-nunito">
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/sign_in" component={SignInForm} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/trips" component={TestPage} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

Few points to add into the question:

1. I confirm that Redirection does happen in `PrivateRoute` (I tested this by changing the `to` param to another route, and I see the URI changes in my browser).
2. If I go directly to `/sign_in`, **it works fine**. The only problem is only when `<Redirect>` does it.
3. My last resort will be to hackishly doing native browser redirect if this can not be solved. But, I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Here are my previous attempts that I have tried;

1. Using `withRouter` in my `PrivateRoute` - based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898856/1627271)
2. Sets the `PrivateRoute` not to be `pure` - based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187737/1627271)
3. Tried importing `Redirect` and `withRouter` from `react-router` instead of `react-router-dom`
4. Installed `path-to-regexp@^2.4.0`
5. Use `push` in `Redirect` - Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731472/1627271)

I am currently using `react-router-dom@5.2.0` and `react@^16.2.0`.

Please help, any suggestions is appreciated. Let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: What happens if you remove or change its `component` directive: `<PrivateRoute path="/trips"  />`?

Comment: Hi @GAEfan - It seems like any components will fail to  render there. I changed it to `NotFound` just now to ensure it and it still doesn't behave correctly. I don't think the problem lies there since the fact that if I go directly to `/sign_in` it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I've found the real issue, it seems like all the routes need to be wrapped inside `BrowserRouter`. So here's my final solution;

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="content position-relative">
        <div className="content-container font-nunito">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/sign_in" component={SignInForm} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/trips" component={TestPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

---

**Old:**

I solved it by downgrading `react-router-dom` from `5.2.0` to `4.3.1`.

This seems to fix the issue with a bit of side-effect [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007905/react-router-with-react-16-6-suspense-invalid-prop-component-of-type-object/53019873)

So my final changes is;

**package.json**

```
- "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
+ "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

**index.js** (To avoid the side effect)

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={props => <LandingPage {...props} />} />
    <Route path="/sign_in" component={props => <SignInForm {...props} />} />

    <PrivateRoute path="/trips" component={props => <TestPage {...props} />} />
</Switch>
```